Is it possible to change the design of wizard steps in SFMC journey builder activity

Is it possible to change design of wizard steps in custom journey builder activity.
I'd like them to look something like this

Thanks in advance.

I've resolved this by adding wizardVisible: false to wizardSteps objects in config.json which removes the steps header. I'll add the path component manually.
